# How to hide followers/following on GitHub?

Tags: github

Is it possible to hide who follows me and who I follow from my profile? I feel like this should be an option for personal opsec. If not, is there anywhere I can request this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/setting-your-profile-to-private**

As of now, there is no setting for this, to request feedback go to: https://github.com/github/feedback, specifically here, the profile help: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/categories/profile-feedback, or here, general feedback: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/categories/general-feedback, or even here: https://github.community/c/github-help/48.

I have tried my very best in searching, and the only profile items GitHub allows you to hide are 1) the PRO badge (this is the only one I have, not sure about other badges), and 2) your private contributions. I do not think there is a beta for this either.

Comment: It’s a security issue for some people, I hope they will fix it

Comment: It seems like they've added an option to mark profiles as private (late 2022). https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-29-private-profiles-are-now-generally-available/. Updated my answer.